# Running commands on Putty without fear of losing connection

Tags: linux, ssh, remote, gnu-screen, putty

How do you use the "screen" command effectively?
Is it:

1. Type "screen"
2. Type in command
3. Lose connection
4. Check back on lost session

How do I carry out step 4?

Answer (score 23):

With screen:

1. `screen`
2. type `command`
3. (Optional: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to detach from the screen)
4. logoff from the session
5. `screen -RD` to reattach to the screen (if there's more than one you'll get a list of current screen sessions and you'll have to supply the session number) from a new session

A simpler method that is useful for commands that leave logfiles or just throw some relevant output and do not need interactivity is `nohup`:

1. `nohup command > logfile`
2. Logoff from the session
3. `tail -f logfile` from a new session

Comment: Note: step 3 is entirely optional. If you close your PuTTY session without detaching, you can still reattach with `screen -RD`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I have picked up about using screen (which I, too, have just started doing):

- `screen -S <name>` creates a screen named '<name>'. This is quite useful if you want to have several screen sessions going at the same time. For instance, I have one I use normally and one I use for my persistent processes.
- `screen -ls` lists the running screens.
- `screen -r <name>` resumes a detached screen. If the screen is already attached somewhere, use `screen -dr <name>`.

Also, when you start using screen, whenever you plan to leave, press `^a d` (= **ctrl-a** followed by a **d**) to detach the screen you're currently running. It can then be resumed later.

In addition, I can recommend taking a look at `^a ?` for a list of the different commands you can use while inside of a screen.

The most important of these (to me) are:

- `^a c` to create a new window in your screen session.
- `^a ^a` to switch between the two last used windows.
- `^a "` to list the current windows in your session.
- `^a Esc` to scroll in your screen buffer.
- `^a k` to kill the current window.
- `^a x` to lock your screen session, in case you need to leave your computer and don't want people to mess with it.

Answer (score 4):

Screen is *really* powerful, and allows you to do exactly what you asked.

To see all your sessions, type

```
screen -list
```

Once you've identified a screen session to reconnect too, try

```
screen -dr SCREENID
```

which will nicely detach and re-attach your session.

You can also do a less nice,

```
screen -D -R
```

which will detach and logout remotely, if nesscessary, then reattach, or if that session doesn't exist, it will create it and notify the user.  You can add a "-t NAME" to give shells or programs a title.

Within screen, use

```
command-c
```

to create a new window (So you don't need 4000000 screen sessions to disconnect and reconnect from), and change between them with

```
command-int
```

Indexing from 0, of course:P

Since you seem a bit unfamiliar with screen, I'm going to assume you could use some other info.  I like the following commands, like:

```
-e xy
```

Which causes x to be the command character and y to be the character to generate a literal command character.  The defaults are Ctrl-a and `a.

There's some more for you here: [Screen!  It's what's for programmers](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6664/1/)

Answer (score 2):

`screen -dr` to detach and resume the previous screen session.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search found this screen guide

http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-tutorials/general-tutorials/using-screen/

So from step b) you can detach the screen using :

"Ctrl - A" "d"

and then later after the connection has been lost and your connected once again find the screen using :

`# screen -ls`

and then reattach using :

`# screen -r <screen_session_name>`

Answer (score 1):

you can also set up your environment to log you in and start screen right off the bat.  There are many ways to do it.  I chose to add this to my .bashrc file.

```
# screen management
if [ $SSH_TTY ] && [ ! $WINDOW ]; then
  SCREENLIST=`screen -ls | grep 'Attached'`
  if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
    echo -e "Screen is already running and attached:\n ${SCREENLIST}"
  else
    screen -U -R
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be looking for

```
screen -x
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 4 is "screen -r"

If you got disconnected really forcefully, you might need to do "screen -r -d", to force it to disconnect from your old ssh session, which it thinks is still open.

Answer (score 0):

```
 For windows system

 Open putty 
 then login in server
```

If you want to see screen in Console then you have to write command

```
 Screen -ls
```

if you have to access the screen then you have to use below command

```
 screen -x screen id
```